# Why do I get weird values after reading from file into array?

Tags: c++, arrays, file, file-io, input

I am pretty novice at C++. Basically what I am trying to do is to read a file into any array and display it, but what happens is that a garbage values appears when running the code below. What exactly I am missing?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    int array_size = 1024;
    char*array = new char[array_size];

    int position = 0;
    ifstream fin("Map.txt");
    if (fin.is_open()) {
        while (!fin.eof() && position < array_size) {
            fin.get(array[position]);
            position++;
        }
        array[position - 1] = '\0';

        cout << "Displaying array......" << endl << endl;

        for (int i = 0; array[i] != '0'; i++) {
            cout << array[i];
        }
    } else {
        cout << "File could not be opened" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: what exact output/error are you getting?

Comment: `void main()` is for chumps. use `int main()`

Comment: According to standards, main must return int

Comment: What does your file look like? Does it contain any numbers?

Comment: [why while(!feof()) is always wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: `char[array_size];` this is already using c++ extensions, the array size must be a constant expression.

Comment: `array[i] != '0'` what is the significance of this condition?

Comment: You have a typo. `array[i] != '0'` needs to be `array[i] != '\0'`.

Comment: it doesn't contain any numbers only characters

Comment: I am not getting an error, I am getting a garbage values filling out the array in the output

Comment: well thanks  all I guess I had a typo that I didn't notice :/ writing '0' instead of '\0'

Comment: you aren't deleting `array` anywhere, but really you should be using `std::vector<char> array(array_size);`

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that your for loop condition is wrong. You should not be comparing array[i] against '0' because that is the ASCII character 0 whose value is actually 48.

You want to compare array[i] against the "null-terminating character" which is '\0' whose value *is* 0.

Comment: Problems that can be resolved by fixing a typo should not be answered. They are not useful to anybody else. They need to be closed.